# How do I connect to PotgreSQL Database trough PHP?

Tags: php, postgresql

How can I connect with my PostgreSQL database trough PHP? I try this

```
$PG_Con = pg_connect("host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 user=user password=pass");
pg_database("db");
$PG_Users = pg_query($PG_Con, "SELECT * FROM users_mfuser WHERE user_ptr_id='71'");
$user2 = pg_fetch_assoc($PG_Users);
```

But it doesen't seems to work. Here is the entire code, can someone help me:

```
    <?php
    include "include/functions.php";
    $id = (int) $_GET['id'];
    $catid = (int) $_GET['cat'];
    if ($catid == NULL) {
        echo "Променливата е празна !";
    } else {
        print functionCat("" . $catid . "");
        functionConnect("pozdrawi");
        $SQL_Song = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM songs WHERE id='$id'");
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($SQL_Song);
        $url = $row['link'];
        $number = explode(":", $url);
        $i = substr($number[2], 0, 2);
        $link1 = "http://media.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv";

        if (@fopen("http://media.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv", "r")) {
            $adres = "http://media.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv";
        } elseif (@fopen("http://media02.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv", "r")) {
            $adres = "http://media02.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv";
        } elseif (@fopen("http://media03.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv", "r")) {
            $adres = "http://media03.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv";
        } elseif (@fopen("http://media04.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv", "r")) {
            $adres = "http://media04.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv";
        } elseif (@fopen("http://media05.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv", "r")) {
            $adres = "http://media05.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv";
        } elseif (@fopen("http://media06.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv", "r")) {
            $adres = "http://media06.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv";
        } elseif (@fopen("http://media07.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv", "r")) {
            $adres = "http://media07.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv";
        } elseif (@fopen("http://media08.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv", "r")) {
            $adres = "http://media08.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv";
        } elseif (@fopen("http://media09.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv", "r")) {
            $adres = "http://media09.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv";
        } elseif (@fopen("http://media10.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv", "r")) {
            $adres = "http://media10.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv";
        } elseif (@fopen("http://media11.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv", "r")) {
            $adres = "http://media11.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv";
        } elseif (@fopen("http://media12.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv", "r")) {
            $adres = "http://media12.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv";
        } elseif (@fopen("http://media13.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv", "r")) {
            $adres = "http://media13.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv";
        } elseif (@fopen("http://media14.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv", "r")) {
            $adres = "http://media14.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv";
        } elseif (@fopen("http://media15.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv", "r")) {
            $adres = "http://media15.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv";
        } elseif (@fopen("http://media16.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv", "r")) {
            $adres = "http://media16.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv";
        } elseif (@fopen("http://media17.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv", "r")) {
            $adres = "http://media17.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv";
        } elseif (@fopen("http://media18.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv", "r")) {
            $adres = "http://media18.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv";
        } elseif (@fopen("http://media19.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv", "r")) {
            $adres = "http://media19.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv";
        } elseif (@fopen("http://media20.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv", "r")) {
            $adres = "http://media20.vbox7.com/s/$i/$number[2].flv";
        }
mysql_close();
        $PG_Con = pg_connect("host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 user=user password=pass");
        pg_database("db");
        $PG_Users = pg_query($PG_Con, "SELECT * FROM users_mfuser WHERE user_ptr_id='71'");
        $user2 = pg_fetch_assoc($PG_Users);

if ($user2['user_song_credits'] == 0) {
            print "<center>asd</center>";
        } elseif ($user2['user_song_credits'] > 0) {
    ?><br />
            <center><div id='mediaspace'>Трябва да имате инсталиран Flash Player за да слушате</div></center>
            <script type='text/javascript'>
                var so = new SWFObject('player.swf','mpl','350','20','9');
                so.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');
                so.addParam('allowscriptaccess','never');
                so.addParam('wmode','opaque');
                so.addVariable('backcolor','8454c6');
                so.addVariable('frontcolor','FFFFFF');
                so.addVariable('lightcolor','FFFFFF');
                so.addVariable('screencolor','0f0f0f');;
                so.addVariable('menu','over');
                so.addVariable('file','<?= $adres ?>&menu=false');
                so.write('mediaspace');
            </script><br />

<?php
pg_close($PG_Con);
functionConnect("pozdrawi");
         echo "Сега свири: <b>".$row['author']." - ".$row['name']."</b>";

        }
        $i = 0;
        $Play_Song = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM songs WHERE cat_id='$catid'");
        echo "<center>
              <a href='javascript: show()'>Playlist</a><br />
              <div class='playlist' align='left' style='display:none;'>";

        while ($play = mysql_fetch_array($Play_Song)) {
            $i = $i + 1;
            $song_cat = $play['cat_id'];
            $Play_Cat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM songs_cat WHERE id='$song_cat'");
            $cat = mysql_fetch_array($Play_Cat);
            $category = $cat['cat_name'];
            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;$i.<a href='song.php?cat=" . $catid . "&id=" . $play['id'] . "'>" . $play[author] . "-" . $play[name] . "</a><br />";
        }
        echo "</div>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure your Postgre is running ?

Comment: What's the error you are getting? *"doesen't seems to work"* is not listed as an error message in the Postgres manual

Comment: My Postgresql is running i have a django site everything is OK, but when i load the php page with the pg connection it gives me white screen ;s

Comment: "white screen", do you report all errors (// Report all PHP errors 
error_reporting(E_ALL); , or see in php.ini)

Answer (score 2):

Check the Postgres [`pg_connect`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-connect.php) page: You need to specify the database name in the connection string and the function `pg_database` does not seem to exist at all.

Comment: Without a specific database name, the username will be used to select the a database with the same name. If this database doesn't exist, you get an error. But when the coder ignores error messages... :(

Comment: @Frank Heikens Yep, and when you call a function that does not exist, execution stops and it doesn´t seem to work...

Answer (score 0):

Turn error reporting on and show them:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// rest of your code
?>
```

Did you change php.ini use the extension php_pgsql? And is this extension working as well? check phpinfo() to be sure.

<strike>Edit: You don't do anything with the results from PostgreSQL, is that correct?</strike>

Comment: `$user2` is a row from the PostgreSQL query.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a database abstraction library.  I like ADOdb but there are others.  This allows porting the code to say mySQL or other database much easier and hides some of the complexities of calling pg_? functions directly.

Also try using empty string '' for the host and port.  Since your connecting to localhost it might be the server only accepts unix socket connections and not TCP connections.

As Frank noted there is no error so maybe your connection is working and your SQL statement is wrong?

Comment: "complexities" ? What is complex in the usage of pg_connect(), pg_query() and pg_fetch_all() ? Maybe you want to use pg_query_params() as well, but these functions are all extremely simple. But if you don't read the PHP-manual, not even for the most simple things, you're out of luck. ADOdb is not going to help against not-reading-the-manual as well.